# Remaining Rows Double After Deleting Row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am able to successfully delete rows from my table view but after a row is removed, the remaining rows are doubled. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            let documentName = documentIds[indexPath.row]
            self.documentIds.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            deleteItemDocumentAt(index: indexPath.row, name: documentName)
            self.collectionItems.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }    
    }
```

deleteItemDocumentAt deletes the correct document from Firebase.

```
func deleteItemDocumentAt(index: Int, name: String) {
        let itemToDelete = self.collectionItems[index]
        let imageUrls = itemToDelete["images"] as? [String]
        if imageUrls != nil && (imageUrls?.count)! > 0 {
            for url in imageUrls! {
                deleteImagesFrom(location: url)
            }
        }

        db.collection("users/\(currentUser.emailAddress!)/collections/\(self.collectionName!)/\(self.collectionName!) Items").document(name).delete() { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error removing document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Document successfully removed!")
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

**This screenshot is before the delete:**
[image]

**This screenshot is after the delete. The remains row appears twice.**
[image]

Comment: You are probably fetching your data again from the db and after the fetch appending it, instead of merging.

Comment: Once try this and let us know result:
 self.tableView.beginUpdates()   
//delete row here//
 self.tableView.endUpdates()

Comment: @guru I tried that with no luck.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I'm not fetching any data again. The only thing I'm doing with Firebase when deleting the row is deleting the corresponding document from Firebase.

Comment: @guru `beginUpdates/endUpdates` is pointless. It has no effect at all for a single `delete` operation.

Comment: crazy question but why are you calling reloadData? you have already removed the item from your collection as well as your table view.

Comment: @dniswhite Good question. I've removed that call and still get the same results.

Comment: @raginggoat that would lead me to believe that your datasource actually has two items in it.

Comment: @raginggoat do you see the item fade away and this item replaces it?

Comment: @dniswhite yes. That’s what’s happening

Comment: @dniswhite the data source only has one item in it after the deletion is performed.

Comment: @raginggoat I am kind of at a loss and would need to breakpoint/debug and see things more. I wonder how many rows are being returned when numberOfRows is being called? my guess is that more than 1 is being returned but I am confused why cellForRowAt would be returning the same row data.

Comment: It works if I add self.documentIds.remove(at: index), self.collectionItems.remove(at: index), and self.tableView.reloadData() to my deleteItemDocumentAt() method.

Comment: Actually, that solution only works if there are only two rows. Once there is a third row, the original issue happens again so I'm back to square one.